# ssh tunnel on a openwrt router, and access it from a LAN host

Tags: ssh, proxy, openwrt

Here's the thing. I'd like to access a remote host by ssh, and make a tunnel as a proxy. I did it on my windows computer with Putty. In putty, there is a "tunnels" options, add a dynamic tunnel would do the trick. That is, a (dynamic, that is in the putty's option, I don't really know what it means)tunnel at port 1111, and then I can access the internet though socks5 proxy 127.0.0.1:1111.

But now I want to make the tunnel on my openwrt router, 192.168.1.1, and access the proxy as 192.168.1.1:1111. I want to know how. There are two major question:

1.the proper command of ctl ssh to make a tunnel just as the putty did. I googled a few, but because of the 2nd question, I never know which one is correct.

2.how can I access the tunnel on the router though 192.168.1.1:1111. As I tried before with ss_local(another proxy program), I established a socks locally but it can never be accessed by my another LAN host. Are there some firewall things to do?

Does anyone know the answers? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to access remotely to my AP.
I used a SSH Reverse Tunnel to a remote server. Here I dump a simple script to achieve it.

```
key_ssh=/root/.ssh/id_rsa
user=root
ip='YOUR_SERVER_IP'
port='THE_PORT_YOU_WANT_TO_CONNECT_THROUGH'

#connect ssh
ssh -f -N -i $key_ssh -R 0.0.0.0:$port:localhost:22 $user@$ip
```

And in your remote server you type:

```
sudo su
ssh -p THE_PORT_YOU_WANT_TO_CONNECT_THROUGH localhost
```

You will be asked for the root password, type it and you're in.